# Configure HTTP SPN for a domain user account on Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: windows, iis, http, kerberos, spn

I have a Windows 2012R2 Server and I would like to use Kerberos authentication with my IIS web applications. How do I set the SPN and map the users for HTTP and HTTPS services for a given use account in Active Directory?